# On Submit, action not going to controller in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

If I am clicking on submit button in cshtml file then action is not going to controller. I have already created the GET method for that. But posting only post method. Get is working fine..

**MODEL**

```
public class ABCModel

{
    public int ABCQueryId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Query cannot be more than 100 characters long.")]
    [Display(Name = "Query Title*")]
    public string QueryTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Specific Notes *")]
    public string SpecificNotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime QueryDate;      
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string SupportDocument { get; set; }       

}
```

**Cshtml Page**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ABC", "Queries", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "content", LoadingElementId = "mask" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "intake_form", @class = "inline-form clear_both" }))

 {
   <div id="intake_sheet_1" style="visibility: visible">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ABC.ABCQueryId)


 @{
   String errorMessage = "";
    if (Session["errorMessage"] != null)
    {
     errorMessage = Session["errorMessage"].ToString();
     }
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
     {
      <span class="pendingtxt" style="color:red;font-size:13px;">@errorMessage</span>
      }
   }

  <div class="form_row">
  <div class="form_col1">
  <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
     Title*</label>
    </div>
   <div class="form_col2" style="z-index: 24; position: relative;" id="queryTitle_div">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ABC.QueryTitle, new { @class = "text QueryFormTextBox" })          <br />
    <div style="float: left">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ABC.QueryTitle)
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_col1">
           <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
             Specific Notes</label>
         </div>
      <div class="form_col2" style="z-index: 21; position: relative;"  id="specific_note_div">
       @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ABC.SpecificNotes, new { @class = "text QueryFormTextBox", style = "resize:none;height:160px;" })
       <br />
       <div style="float: left">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ABC.SpecificNotes)             </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_col1">
         <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
           Supporting Document
            </label>
           </div>
          <div class="form_col2">
            <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ABC.SupportDocument, new { @Id = "lblFileName", @readonly = "readonly" })
              </div>
            <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
                <button id='btnUploadPopup' type="button" style="float:left;"  onclick="javascript:OpenFileUpload();">
                   Upload Files</button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
         <div class="form_row form_footer">
           <p class="indent">
               <input class="primary button float_right" value="Submit" type="submit" name="button" />

            </p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

**Controller**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ABC(ABCViewModel model, string button)
    {

            QURManager manager = new QURManager();
            if (Session["userDetails"] != null)
            {
                manager = new QURManager((RegModel)Session["userDetails"]);
            }
            String errorMessage = "";
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                errorMessage = errorMessage + " Fields can not be empty.";
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                Session["errorMessage"] = errorMessage;
                IABC data = new ABCViewModel();

                data.ABC.QueryTitle = model.ABC.QueryTitle;
                data.ABC.SpecificNotes = model.ABC.SpecificNotes;
                data.ABC.SupportDocument = model.ABC.SupportDocument;

                TempData["isEdit"] = false;
                return View("ABC", data);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["errorMessage"] = "";
                Session.Remove("errorMessage");
            }

            Session["fileName"] = null;
            AssignSession.UpdateRegisterUserSession();

            return View();           
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it should work assuming that the Controller name is "QueriesController".  I copied your code into a new project and works (can't upload files) but other then that, the request went to the correction controller action.

Comment: @SBurris In my project its not working even without uploading the files. any ideas?

Comment: @SajjadHashmi what do you mean? I didnt get you?

Comment: @SBurris I have checked by using the breakpoints in VS.. It is not even going to controller in post action..

Comment: What is your controller name ? is it QueriesController ?

Comment: @CodeXerox are there any `JS` errors in the browser console?

Comment: Try two things: 1) make sure the HTTP Request is sending to the right URL with the right data (identifies problem on HTML side) 2) Remove the parameters form the Controller action to see if the action is called that way (identifies problem with the mapper)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are mentioning the correct name for your controller as per your example your controller name should be `QueriesController`

Than sure that you have included following scripts in your page:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in your `web.config` you have this present:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Means MicrosoftAjax.. I have used "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"